# RxJava2 Group Objects by Id to HaspMap and sort them

Tags: android, group-by, observable, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have Observable that returns

```
List<Item>
```

Every Item has

```
long groupId
long dateMillis
```

I want to group that list to

```
HashMap<groupId, <List<Item>>
```

with sorted items in each map entry by dateMillis.

Could anyone help me to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
    Observable<List<Item>> listObservable;
    listObservable.flatMap(Observable::from)
            .toSortedList((item, item2) -> Long.compare(item.dateMillis, item2.dateMillis))
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .subscribe(item -> addToHashMap(item));
```

Sort list and later add items to map.

Comment: yeah, it looks like the way to go